# Why is QT only listing one microphone device on iOS?

Tags: ios, qt

I'm having some trouble finding documentation on how to select the top front microphone on iOS using QT. How is it done?

The following code:

```cpp
QList<QAudioDevice> devices = QMediaDevices::audioInputs();
    for(const auto& deviceInfo: devices) {
        qDebug() << "Device name:" << deviceInfo.id();
        qDebug() << "Supported sample rates:" << deviceInfo.minimumSampleRate()<< "; " << deviceInfo.maximumSampleRate();
        qDebug() << "Supported channel counts:" << deviceInfo.minimumChannelCount() << "; " << deviceInfo.maximumChannelCount();
        qDebug() << "Supported codecs:" << deviceInfo.supportedSampleFormats();
        qDebug() << "--------------------------------";
    }
```

only outputs one device which clearly isn't true:

Device name: `"com.apple.avfoundation.avcapturedevice.built-in_audio:0" Supported sample rates: 1 ;  96000 Supported channel counts: 1 ;  16 Supported codecs: QList(UInt8, Int16, Int32, Float)`